# Angular stateParams to controller, $urlRouterProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ionic-framework

I'm building an app with Ionic and AngularJS.

Now I have a page with a list of items. Each item has an ID, and so a click results in something like this:

```
/item/1
```

or

```
/item/2
```

where 1 and 2 are ID's.

Now I have the default state like this, for the homepage with this list:

```
.state('app.home', {
url: "/home/",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "app/home.html"
  },
},
controller: 'HomeCtrl'
```

})

What I want is to pass the paramater to the controller. What I found is the following solution, but this isn't working. The reason is that it doesn't know which controller to use (in above example, `HomeCtrl` is specified.).

```
.state('app.item', {
url: "/item/:id",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "app/item.html"
  },
},
controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
}
```

})

As you can see `controller` now has a function, but where do I specify the actual controller to use?
Also, is this the right way or is there a better/easier way?

Comment: controller: 'controllerName' should work here.

Comment: And how would the params get to that controller? And how to access them there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.controller('controllerName',
    [       '$scope','$stateParams'
    function($scope , $stateParams ) {    
        // 
        $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
```

In $stateParams.id , id will be name of parameter you define in url(:id).

Comment: So you don't have to do anything special in the .state()?

Comment: Nope, I don't think you need to do anything special to get parameters value.

Comment: Or you need more explanation then check here. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Answer (score 0):

By the way - a cleaner way of doing this is:

```
angular.extend($scope, $stateParams);
```

This will copy the `$stateParams` keys to the `$scope` you're in.