# How to use query parameters with UI Router, without defining all of them first

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my application there are a *lot* of possible query parameters, and currently, I have to define them all:

```
.state('app.home', {
    url: '/home/?date&from&to&website&settings&search..',
    controller: function($transition$) {
        console.log($transition$.params());
    }
}
```

But this has two downsides. I have to define *every possible param*, and when it's not set, it's added to `$transition$.params()` as `myParam: undefined`.

---

Is there a more convenient way to set query parameters with *UI Router 1.x* (so without `$stateParams` or `$location`)?

Something like:

```
`url: '/home/?myParams`
```

Comment: what about checking them directly? e.g. `if($stateParams.date){...}`. Also less convenient: `url: '/home/?myParams*`. The `*` will consider an arbitrary number of parameters as a single string

Comment: I'd rather not use `$stateParams`, as Ui Router stated I should use `$transition$` with its lifecycle hooks (question updated).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684658/angular-stateparams-to-controller-urlrouterprovider

Comment: @RITESHARORA Thanks, but that solution uses `$scope`, which I don't use, to avoid so called *Scope soup*.

Comment: .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home/?date&from&to&website&settings&search..',
    controller: function($transition$,$stateParams) {
        console.log($transition$.params());
        console.log($stateParams)
    }
}